# regularity condition for a solution of a parabolic PDE on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (can be taken parallelizable if needed) a second order differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ can be expressed in a local chart as

$$
\mathcal{L}f(x)= \left(a^{ij}(x) \partial_i \partial_j+ b^j(x) \partial_j +c(x)\right)f(x)
$$
The operator is said uniformly elliptic (w.r. to $g$) if, given an atlas $\{(U_\alpha,(x^i)_\alpha)\}$ exists a constant $C>0$ such that in any chart

$$
a^{ij}(x) \xi_i\xi_j \ge C g^{ij}(x) \xi_i\xi_j
$$
It is immediate that a uniformly elliptic operator is elliptic.

Let now $u(t,x)$ a classical solution of the Cauchy problem

\begin{align} 
\label{parabolic}(\partial_t -\mathcal{L}) u(t,x)&=0\\
u(0,x)&=f(x)
\end{align}
Where $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Is a smooth function.
If we assume the coefficients to be smooth functions  it is true that $\mathcal{L}u(t,x)$ is a solution for the Cauchy problem? i.e has $\mathcal{L}u(t,x)$ the same regularity of $u(t,x)$?

EDIT:

If the manifold is compact the result should follow. Indeed it is possible to prove that for compact manifolds any elliptic operator is the generator of a Feller semi-group.  For a dense classe of functions the semigroup can be written as $e^{tA}$. By the Kolmogorov backward formula.  for any such function $e^{tA}f$ is a solution of the PDE.

If the function is taken to be smooth of course $u(t,x):=e^{tA}f(x)$ is smooth in $t$ and in $x$.

I am not abke to characterize in any useful way the set of functions for which this works.

Comment: (Not an answer as I don't know much Analysis) but if $\mathcal {L}$ is self-adjoint and has discrete spectrum  (this is the case of the Laplacian on compact manifolds) then is diagonalizable, with smooth eigenfunctions. Your system of equations then splits and can be solved separately in each mode, then it's easy to check that the behaviour on each mode is esponential, hence smooth. 

But I'm curious to see what an expert may say, in more general cases. 
I would be curious to see if exists a general regularity theorem for parabolic PDEs.

Comment: @Overflowian thanks for the comment. Now that i think about it it isn't necessary for the operator to be self-adjoint either in the case of compact manifold and i think any classical solution in that case has to be smooth, but i don't know in the non-compact case

Comment: The initial condition on u is weird, is u a function from M to M

Comment: @ArcticChar you're right. $u: \mathbb{R}^+ \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Marco Is your manifold smooth?

Comment: @JackT yes, the manifold Is $C^\infty$ smooth